# How to delete all child nodes and relationships using single query in Neo4j.?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a tree like node structure in my Neo4j DB. When I delete particular node I want to delete all child nodes and relationships related to that node. 
Consider node structure generated by below query,

```
merge (p1:Person{nic:'22222v'})-[r1:R1]->(p2:Person{nic:'33333v'}) 
merge(p1)-[r2:R2]->(p3:Person{nic:'44444v'}) 
merge(p2)-[r3:R3]->(p3) 
merge (p3)-[r4:R4]->(p4:Person{nic:'55555v'}) 
merge(p4)-[r5:R5]->(p5:Person{nic:'66666v'}) 
return r1,r2,r3,r4,r5
```

If I input node(nic:44444v) it should delete node(nic:44444v),node(nic:55555v),node(nic:66666v
), relationship(r2),relationship(r3),relationship(r4) and relationship(r5)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use multiple depth relationships and delete the nodes :

```
MATCH (n:Person {nic:'44444v'})-[*0..]->(x)
DETACH DELETE x
```

The `0..` depth definition will embed the `n` identifier in the `x` nodes and thus will handle the case where the person doesn't have children nodes.

Alternative syntax for oldier neo4j versions :

```
MATCH (n:Person {nic:'44444v'})-[*0..]->(x) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (x)-[r]-() 
DELETE r, x
```

Comment: It PROBABLY doesn't need to be said, but just in case... Try to use relationship labels in this kind of recursive operation. Otherwise, if any of those nodes happens to have some kind of relationship breaking out of that tree structure to any other node in your db, you're going to start a recursive delete that could have the potential to wipe out a good portion, maybe even all, of your db. Even if there are no relationships that escape that tree in your current design, a future db change might add additional relationships that sets things up for disaster later.

Comment: @Christophe, Does your query work in Neo4j 2.3.0-M02. Because it gave me syntax errors.

Comment: M02 is a milestone release, not sure and you should use a stable version as 2.3 GA was released in october 2015 ! What are your syntax errors ?

Comment: @Christophe, DETACH gave me again a syntax error, I think my version not supported for it.

Comment: @Hasitha would be nice to post the syntax error you get. Anyway I added an alternative syntax for older versions.